# How to read special characters of a XML file with minidom

Tags: python, xml, dom, minidom

When reading data from a XML file, I cannot get the right string.
My XML file is like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<Root>
   <Name>aa é bb</Name>
</Root>
```

I would like to read the `<Name>` balise correctly.
So I try the command:

```
NameValue = Item.getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].data
```

Which returns `u'aa \xc3\xa9 bb'` in `NameValue`.
So how can I get `u'aa é bb'` or `'aa é bb'` in `NameValue` ?
I have tried encode and decode functions without success.

I would like to do that with Python 2.7.

Comment: u already get the right unicode value. do u mean the output encoding?  try  print u'aa \xc3\xa9 bb'.encode("latin1")

Comment: I would like to compare NameValue with another variable containing u'aa é bb'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have it.
I managed to do that with :

```
NameValue = unicode(Item.getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].data.encode("latin-1"), "utf-8")
```

Thanks for your help fanlix